# What height is needed to drop a $72\ \rm{kg}$ mass to impart a $5000\ \rm{g}$ shock onto a test piece

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I am trying to design a simple drop / shock testing machine.

We want to rate our products to be shock rated to $5000\ \rm g$.

In order to test our products to $5000\ \rm g$ I plan on dropping a weight onto the product imparting a shock. (See drawing)

[image: Drop Test Rig]

My question is;
How high would I need to drop my $72\ \rm{kg}$ weight from the test piece in order to rate by product to survive a $5000\ \rm g$ shock.

I understand that the impulse time and distance is quite critical in the final numbers regarding the calucations. Lets say for calucation sake, that both materials were to be steel.

Comment: I am confused by what a $5000\ \rm g$ shock means. Also this might be better suited on engineering SE

Comment: I disagree @AaronStevens. I think, this boils down to a very simple calculation and is not really complex engineering... Provided, the 5000g shock is explained in more detail.

Comment: @lmr I don't think I said anything about *complex* engineering. In any case this is why it takes 5 votes to put a question on hold/migrate it. I am fine with others not agreeing with me :)

Comment: If you want to subject the product to a momentary _acceleration_ that is 5000 times the acceleration due to gravity, then a better way to achieve that might be to drop the product onto a hard surface instead of dropping a hard object onto the product.

Comment: Hi all, I too am confused by what a 5000g shock means. See this is how industry rates items, for instance you would buy a watch with a 1000g shock rating. Obviously I know 5000g is an acceleration. I was hoping someone could clarify that for me.

Comment: Regarding which site it should be on. I too was unsure, it's a physics question in an engineering application. I was going to post it to both, but you must wait 40 minutes between.

Comment: Seems that the relevant standard for watches is https://www.iso.org/standard/62753.html, I haven't read it but it seems that the g's are not that important. Can provide a reference about the g rating? Anyway, since this seems to be an informal test, I guess you could define your own criteria.

Comment: @LukeThomas, how long does it take for the steel drop table to come to rest once it strikes its target?  THAT is the information needed to provide an answer to your question.  To avoid directly answering this question, have you thought of installing an accelerometer on your drop table?

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that you want to test the material being impacted. If what you want to test is how well the internals of your object (internal electronics, for example, or the durability of a product during shipping), then this impact test will not give the results you want.

There is no one single height that will get you the shock you require. Let's take this step-by-step.

Your test object must withstand a $5\,000g$ shock, which means it must be able to sustain, at least momentarily, an acceleration ($a_T$, the $T$ referring to the test object) of at least $5\,000g$.
$$a_T > 5\,000g$$
Multiply both sides of the equation by the mass of the test object ($m_T$) gets us the required force to be applied to the test object ($F_T$) by Newton's second law ($F=ma$).
$$m_Ta_{min} > 5\,000m_Tg$$
$$F_T > 5\,000m_Tg$$
By Newton's third law, the force experienced by the test object is equal to the force the falling mass experiences on impact.
$$F_F > 5\,000m_Tg$$
where $F_F$ is the force experienced by the falling mass.

The acceleration of the falling mass can be found with another application of Newton's second law.
$$m_Fa_F > 5\,000m_Tg$$
Here, $m_F$ is the mass of the falling weight ($72\,000\,\textrm{kg}$) and $a_F$ is the acceleration it experiences on impact.

Finally, we can write an expression for the acceleration that the falling weight must experience to put the required shock on the test object.
$$a_F > 5\,000g\left(\frac{m_T}{m_F}\right)$$

You cannot determine ahead of time what the required drop height is because it is different for different materials. Imagine dropping the weight onto a mattress versus a concrete floor. The mattress will experience a much smaller shock because the falling weight decelerates over a much longer distance compared to the concrete floor. You can only find out what shock your test object experienced by measuring the acceleration of the falling weight.

So, the procedure for testing your product is

1. Attach an accelerometer to the falling weight.
2. Drop the weight onto your test object.
3. Retrieve the accelerometer data and see if the required acceleration was attained.
4. If the acceleration recorded in step 3 was not large enough, then repeat the test with the falling weight starting at a higher starting height or use a larger falling weight.

For step 4, the impact shock should scale as the square root of the drop height. This means that, if you need to double the shock, you need to quadruple the drop height. Tripling the shock requires a nine-times larger drop height. The same goes for the mass of the falling weight: quadrupling the mass results in twice the shock.

Comment: Do your calculations apply here? The test object will barely move, since the support is fixed to the earth (the mass is approximately infinite). This is an indication that dropping a hammer is not a good method to obtain great accelerations, instead the test object should be dropped.

Comment: @jinawee I'm assuming the test is indicative of damage to the object due to an impulse acceleration, namely an impact. If this is the case, then it doesn't matter which part is moving, only that the forces generated would cause 5000g acceleration in the test object. If it's more similar to the "watch with 1000g shock rating" in his comment, then my answer is wrong (hence the first paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

1. What's a shock test?

I would have thought that a 5000 g product shock test is to test the ability of what's inside the box to survive rapid deceleration without the internals ripping themselves off their enclosure mounts. Dropping a weight onto a static box won't test this at all if the enclosure doesn't move or flex. Shouldn't you be dropping the product?

2. 72 kg weight?

It's not clear you have chosen a 72 kg weight.

3. Required velocity

5000 g is a deceleration of roughly 50,000 m/s². If, for example, this is to be achieved with a 1 mm deflection of the top surface of the product then we can calculate the required impact speed from
$ a = \frac {v^2}{2 s}  $ so for our figures we get $ v = \sqrt {2sa} = \sqrt {2 \times 0.001 \times 50000} = 10 \ \text {m/s} $.

To accelerate the product to 10 m/s by a frictionless gravity drop the height is $ s = \frac {v^2}{2a} = \frac {10^2}{2\times 9.81} = 5.09 \ \text m $.

Note that mass doesn't appear in any of the calculations.

---

I do not work in this field so maybe I'm missing some key knowledge.

Comment: So when you jump from a 1 m high wall you touch down at 100 m/s? ;-)

Comment: Darn. I'm tired and was expecting a larger number but believed my maths. Can you spot my error?

Comment: "Shouldn't you be dropping the product?" - Maybe it doesn't matter whether you jump from a 30 m high bridge, or earth jumps 30 m towards you. The force is the same, isn't it?

Comment: Frictionless gravity acceleration is not 5000g, it's 1g = 9.81 m/s².

Comment: Also, it should be a=v²/2s, so v=sqrt(2sa) = sqrt(2*1mm*50km/s²) = sqrt(100m²/s²)=10m/s. Always calculate with units. It will help you verify the result

Comment: Duh! Thanks. Almost time for bed. @Thomas, but as I read it, the question isn't about force, but about shock / deceleration. I would agree that a ball hitting a fixed bat at 10 m/s would decelerate at the same rate as a stationary ball being hit by a 10 m/s bat would accelerate but in the OP's case the product can't move. It won't be accelerated at all except for the part that deforms.